# Method that check first and last char if equals

Tags: java, printf

I have this instruction:

Define and test a method called checkString that will take in the word as a parameter and checks whether the String begins and ends with the same letter. If both letters are the same the method returns true otherwise false (returns a boolean). The program treats lower and uppercase letters as equivalent.

Also I need to use the printf statement

Sample output would be:

> Type a string: abba
>
> abba begins and ends with the same letter

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Excercise5 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a string: ");
        String word = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.printf ("%s begins and ends with the same letter." , checkString(word));
    }
    public static boolean checkString (String word) {
        int length = word.length();
        word = word.toUpperCase(); //since you are testing them as upper case
        char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
        char lastLetter = word.charAt(length - 1);
        return firstLetter == lastLetter;
    }
}
```

Comment: try something at least

Comment: What is your question? Is there an error? Which part are you stuck at?

Comment: my program prints "false begins and ends with the same letter." if the first and last char is not equal and it prints "true begins and ends with the same letter." how do i just make it print `word + begins and ends with the same letter` if the 1st and last char is true??

Comment: A simple if-else statement is all you really needed to add to determine what to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you've basically figured it out already, but here's a slightly updated version.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Excercise5{
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a string: ");
        String word = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        if(checkString(word)) {
            System.out.printf("%s begins and ends with the same letter.\r\n" , word);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s does not begin and end with the same letter.\r\n", word);
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkString (String word) {
      int length = word.length();
      word = word.toUpperCase(); //since you are testing them as upper case
      char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
      char lastLetter = word.charAt(length - 1);
      return firstLetter == lastLetter;
   }
}
```

Comment: can i ask what the \r and \n do?

Comment: `\r\n` is the standard way of printing a new line. They stand for carriage return and newline respectively.

Answer (score -2):

The method will return true if the first letter and the last letter of the received String is the same. Otherwise it will return false. In the main: do the required definitions and ask the user to enter a String.